# _SESSION in foreach

Tags: php

i have simple login PDO MSSQL Server

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $username = $_POST['user'];
    $password = $_POST['pass'];
    $hashedPass = passConvert($password);
    // Check If User Exits in Database
    $stmt = $con->prepare("   SELECT [UID]
      ,[ID]
      ,[PWD]
  FROM [kal_auth].[dbo].[Login] WHERE [ID] = '$username' AND [PWD] =$hashedPass  
                                       ");
    $stmt->execute();
    $row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $count = $stmt->rowCount();
    // IF COUNT > 0 This Mean Database Account About Username
    if ($count > 0) {
        foreach ($row as $rows){
            $_SESSION['ID'] = $rows['UID'];
            $_SESSION['Username'] = $rows['ID'];
        }
        header("location:test.php");
    }

}
```

my question is .. make _SESSION in foreach loop was safe or it's not safe  ??

Comment: Should only be looking for 1 row, then you won't need a loop, also as-is its possible to login without a password through SQL injection.

Comment: when i use fetch only i cant find row becuase that i use fetchAll

Comment: how user can login through SQL injection ??

Comment: 1st user (admin?) with a username like `foo' OR 1=1 LIMIT 1 --`

Comment: can u tell me how protect this code from SQL inject ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: thanks my dear :"")